# The gills broke off of my kitchen fan, is it still safe to operate until I can replace it?

Tags: kitchens, exhaust-fan, exhaust-vent, plastic

I live in a dinky apartment and one night, while being completely turned off, The plastic grille over my kitchen fan just fell and shattered on the ground. It seems like the bolt holding it in place snapped off. Anyways, it’s going to take a couple of days before I or my landlord can get replacement parts. Is it still safe to operate the fan without the grille? Or will I be okay to continue cooking on my electric stove without using the fan so long as I don’t cook anything that will result in a lot of smoke? I don’t want to cause any damage to the fan but I’d like to still use my stove in these next few days.

To specify it is a small, Broan ceiling exhaust fan. I have lived here for 2 years and I’ve never had any issues with it aside from the occasional light rattling while in use.

Comment: It should be safe as long as you or anybody else do not stick your fingers in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the fan is mounted on the ceiling you should be OK as long as you don't hit it with a mop or broom stick and don't have any loose birds flying around. If the fan is mounted on a wall or a range hood, I'd avoid using it. It shouldn't be mounted there but sometimes landlords do crazy things.